# ValueError: No Results DataFrame - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my code.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

file='Requirements Upload.xlsx'
x1=pd.ExcelFile(file)
df=x1.parse('Requirements Mapping')

agg_df = (df.fillna('N/A').set_index(['Unique_ID', 'No_of_Filings'])
          .stack()
          .reset_index('No_of_Filings')
          .groupby(0)
          .agg(['sum', 'size'])
          .reset_index())

writer=pd.ExcelWriter("Requirements Output.xlsx",engine="xlsxwriter")
agg_df.to_excel(writer,"Requirements Mapping Output")

writer.save()
```

Here's my data:

```
Unique_ID   No_of_Filings   Req_1   Req_2   Req_3   Req_4
RCONF045    3               Blue    Yellow      
RCONF046    3               Blue    Yellow      
RCONF047    3               Blue    Yellow      
RCONF048    3               Green   Brown       
RCONF051    3               Green   Purple  Orange  Black
RCONF052    3               Green   Purple  Orange  Blue
```

When I run the code, my error is "ValueError: no results", but I can't understand why. Are the blank cells causing a problem?

EDIT: I have added "NA" to all my blank cells, but I still receive the same error.

SECOND EDIT: My source document was pulling these fields using a formula. I blew out the formula to upload into Python, but when I had my dataframe printed, it carried forward those empty fields (even though there was no formula in my upload file). I deleted those rows and now it works!

```
      Unique_ID  No_of_Filings  Req_1   Req_2   Req_3  Req_4
  0   RCONF045            3.0   Blue  Yellow     NaN    NaN
  1   RCONF046            3.0   Blue  Yellow     NaN    NaN
  2   RCONF047            3.0   Blue  Yellow     NaN    NaN
  3   RCONF048            3.0  Green   Brown     NaN    NaN
  4   RCONF051            3.0  Green  Purple  Orange  Black
  5   RCONF052            3.0  Green  Purple  Orange   Blue
  6        NaN            NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
  7        NaN            NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
  8        NaN            NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
  9        NaN            NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
  10       NaN            NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is in those blank cells? DataFrames in pandas don't let you have empty cells

Comment: Do you have NaNs or something?

Comment: what's the output of `agg_df`? it's an empty frame right? I think `group_by(0)` is not right here.

Comment: I added "NA" to all my blank cells, but when I run the program, I'm getting the same error of "no results"

Comment: Can you show the full backtrace? As far as I'm concerned, your error could have happened anywhere, including near the start. Better show where it occurred with a backtrace.

Comment: @ Quickbeam2k1

Your comment helped! Turns out my Excel upload file was pulling "NaN" from rows 8 to 20 (not shown in my dataset above). From my original Excel file, rows 8 to 20 had a formula. When I moved the tab into an upload file, I guess Python was still reading those rows as having a formula (even though there weren't formulas in those rows).

I deleted the blank rows 8 - 20 and tried the program again and it worked.